# Non Commutative sorting in Mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions, sorting

I have been trying to do some oscillator algebra in *Mathematica* and having troubles with sorting and simplifying expressions. I am using the [NCAlgebra](http://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/) package which helps to improve the properties of `NonCommutativeMultiply` in *Mathematica*. However I have to create a huge list of rules to replace terms using the algebra. This quickly becomes impractical since I get these enormous expressions and I have to sift through the terms to see what simplifies and add more rules.

I have been wondering if there is a way to write a sorting function that would take an elementary expression and change it to a list and then permute the elements of list to sort the expression. I am fairly new to Mathematica but I would eventually like to write a small package which would allow me to these kind of manipulations.

For example,
I have terms like $a**b**c**a^\dagger$ where $a$, $b$, $c$, etc. commute with each other but $a**a^\dagger-a^\dagger**a =1$. So I would like to sort things such that all dagger operators are to the left and have *Mathematica* use the fact that $a$, $b$, $c$ commute to rewrite the expressions. Right now I am assigning rules for every type of term that appears in my calculation but the number of terms has become unmanageable.

Comment: Hello Karan, welcome to Mathematica.SE?  Did you mean `a**a(dagger)-a(dagger)**a =1`?  Note that you can also write $\LaTeX$, just surround your expression with dollar signs.

Comment: I was just going to point out what Szabolcs said... I've changed it to $\LaTeX$, but do review the dagger term.

Comment: Thanks for the edit guys. I have corrected it and will remember to format things correctly in future.

Comment: Check section "Some noncommutative algebraic manipulation" from nb available [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/325/)

Answer (score 6):

The trick here is to take control of the non-commuting operators, and to define your own set of rules. Use `prod` as the head of each operator product, where `prod[x,y]` represents `x ** y`, and you can then define rules for manipulating `prod`.

Define rules that move $a^\dagger$ to the left in an operator product.

```
prod[u___, a, ad, v___] := prod[u, ad, a, v] + prod[u, v];
prod[u___, x : b | c, ad, v___] := prod[u, ad, x, v];
```

then you can evaluate

```
prod[a, b, c, ad]

(* prod[b, c] + prod[ad, a, b, c] *)
```

Generalisations of this sort of trick should solve your problem.

Comment: @Karan Stephen's suggestion is good. Does $a^\dagger$, indeed commute with $b$ and $c$, though?

Comment: @Mark Yes $a^\dagger$ does commute with $b$ and $c$. However there is $b^\dagger$ and $c^\dagger$ which doesn't commute with b and c respectively.

Comment: @Stephen That sounds like a good idea. I will try this.

Comment: A more general approach would be to define

`prod[u___, a[i_], ad[j_], v___] := 
  prod[u, ad[j], a[i], v] + prod[u, comm[a[i], ad[j]], v];`

and then to define particular rules for c-number commutators such as

`prod[u___, comm[a[2], ad[1]], v___] := comm[a[2], ad[1]] prod[u, v];`

Comment: @Stephen I tried what you suggested but I ran into troubles. Here is what I did:
`Prod[x___, y___] := x ** y; 
Prod[a___, b_, c_, d___] := Prod[a, c, b, d] + Comm[b, c] Prod[a, d];`Comm[a, $a^\dagger$] = 1; Comm[b, $b^\dagger$] = 1; 
Comm[a, b] = 0; Comm[$a^\dagger$, b] = 0; Comm[a, $b^\dagger$] = 0; 
Comm[$a^\dagger$, $b^\dagger$] = 0; Prod[a, b, $a^\dagger$]. However this gives some errors. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Your definitions are completely different from the ones that I gave, and they are badly behaved anyway - e.g. infinite recursion. Use my definitions for `prod[u___, a, ad, v___]` and `prod[u___, x : b | c, ad, v___]` then evaluate `prod[a, b, ad]` which gives `prod[b] + prod[ad, a, b]`.

Comment: @Stephen Yes I figured out what was wrong and used your definitions and it worked. However it only works if I directly compute the product of oscillators. But if I have variables in terms of oscillators like `X = Prod[a,ad]; Y = Prod[b,ad,a]` and I try to compute `Prod[x,Y]`, it doesn't work. It just leaves it as `Prod((1 + Prod[ad,a])(b + Prod[ad,a,b]))`. How can I make it evaluate the product?

Comment: You must use the notation to write the nested operator product as `prod[1 + prod[ad, a], prod[b] + prod[ad, a, b]]`. Then you need to define some more rules to allow simplification of `prod`. Here is a (simplified) set of rules that will solve your problem:

`prod[u___,x_+y_,v___]:=prod[u,x,v]+prod[u,y,v]; (* expand sums *)`

`prod[u___,x_?NumericQ,v___]:=x prod[u,v]; (* pull out c-numbers *)`

`prod[u___,prod[x___],v___]:=prod[u,x,v]; (* resolve nested prods *)`

which gives the result

`prod[b]+3 prod[ad,a,b]+prod[ad,ad,a,a,b]`

Sorry about the formatting - I couldn't control the linefeeds.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use FeynCalc:

```
[rolfm@localhost ~]$ math
Mathematica 9.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2012 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= FilePrint@"karan"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
(*
If FeynCalc is not already installed, do:
Import["http://www.feyncalc.org/install.m"]
*)
$LoadFeynArts=False;
Quiet@Get["HighEnergyPhysics`FeynCalc`"]
FI;
DeclareNonCommutative[a,b,ad,bd];
Commutator[a, ad] = 1;
Commutator[b, bd] = 1;
Commutator[b, ad] = 0;
Commutator[a, bd] = 0;
Commutator[ad,bd] = 0;
Commutator[a,  b] = 0;
DotSimplify[ a.b.ad ] 

In[2]:= <<karan                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Loading FeynCalc from /home/rolfm/.Mathematica/Applications/HighEnergyPhysics
FeynCalc 8.2.0 Type ?FeynCalc for help or visit http://www.feyncalc.org/
$PrePrint is set to FeynCalcForm. Use FI and FC to change the display format.

Out[2]= b + ad . b . a
```

Comment: Thanks for directing me to the package. It does do the job pretty neatly but somehow it is taking a very long time to do the calculations. I have a lot of expressions and using the DotSimplify on them is taking too long. Is there any way I can speed things up.

Comment: Maybe. Can you send me a notebook with some large expressions?

Answer (score 1):

It would have helped if you have gives a simple example of what you want.

But you could always do something like

```
expr = a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d
Apply[List, expr]
(*  {d, c*x, b*x^2, a*x^3}  *)
```

Now to sort it, use `Sort` and you can apply your sorting function, as described in help:

```
"Sort[list,p] applies the function p to pairs of elements in list to 
determine whether they are in order. The default function p is 
OrderedQ[{#1,#2}]&."
```

You can also use [Permute](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Permute.html) using some permutation group.

If you give a small example of an input, and what you like to get as output it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have edited the question to include an example. I will try what you suggested.