# Define action of noncommutative product of operators

Tags: operators, custom-notation

I have objects wrapped with head fv. So they are things like

```
fv[{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}]
```

I then defined two operators, `a` and `ad` that act on these objects and spit back new objects, also with head fv:

```
a[v /; Head[v] == fv] = ... object returned that looks like fv[{1,2},{3, 4} ...];
ad[v /; Head[v] == fv] = ... object returned that looks like fv[{4, 5}, {6, 7} ...];
op[a] * fv[y_]  ^:= a[fv[y]];
op[ad] * fv[y_] ^:= ad[fv[y]];
```

So now I can evaluate expressions like `op[a]*fv[{1, 2}, {3, 4}]`.

I now want to also be able to evaluate expressions like `op[a]**op[ad]*fv[{1, 2}, {3, 4}]` where the `**` denotes non-commutative multiplication. When I try implementing this with

```
op[a] ** op[ad]*fv[y_] ^:= a[ad[fv[y]]];
```

*Mathematica* tells me that `NonCommutativeMultiply` is protected. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Have a look at the answer that I gave to [Non Commutative sorting in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16063/non-commutative-sorting-in-mathematica/16065#16065), because it contains some tricks that might be sufficient to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following, based on the post 'Non-Commutative Sorting in *Mathematica*', works well. I redefined the operator product so that it produces another object with head `op` and then generalized the definition of the action of these `op` objects.

```
op[x__] ** op[y__] ^:= op[x, y]
op[a] * fv[y__]  ^:= a[fv[y]];
op[x__, a] * fv[y__] ^:= op[x]*a[fv[y]];
...and similarly for ad
```