Modern way of simplifying non-commutative algebraic expressions in 2022
I have been asking about how to do modern quantum optics calculations in 2022, and one potential solution is to use a package that uses noncommutative algebra.
There are currently very old questions asking how to do this in Mathematica, and it seems like the most popular answer is to use the NCAlgebra package. But this question and answer was asked 10-15 years ago, and I'm curious if this is still the modern way that these types are problems are solved.
For example, I might be working with a term involing the multiplication of multiple ladder operators such as:
$$ \frac{1}{4} a_1\cdot a_2^2\cdot a_7{}^{\dagger }\cdot a_2\cdot a_7\cdot a_7{}^{\dagger }, $$
Where $ [ a_i, a_j^\dagger] = \delta_{ij} $.
If I want to try to either re-order these terms or simplify them with information about the commutators, then I'd like the most natural and easy framework to do this. This was answered previously by using ModalForm + the Quantum Mathematica package, but I'm curious if there is a more natural way of doing this, either with newer versions of mathematica or with more general noncommutative tools that are more modern and more powerful.

The simplest approach that I have found for this type of problem (i.e. normal ordering) is described in the answer that I gave to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16063/non-commutative-sorting-in-mathematica/16065#16065. For indexed creation/annihilation operators you would need to define the appropriate commutator using a KroneckerDelta.

@StephenLuttrell, thanks for your answer. I can't get that answer to work, as I end up getting terms like Prod[Prod[a], ad] that wont simplify. I also see that this was adressed in the comments, but I don't have a solution for it. I have also asked my questions about it in a more specific question here:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/301655/simplification-of-quantum-ladder-operators-ideally-using-using-ncalgebra

The definition prod[u___, a[i_], ad[j_], v___] :=    prod[u, ad[j], a[i], v] + KroneckerDelta[i, j] prod[u, v] makes your prod[a[1], a[2], a[2], ad[7], a[2], a[7], ad[7]] normal-order correctly.
